# web hosting plan for portfolio site

Tags: web-hosting

I'm currently creating my personal website right now. The website is only a portfolio site to display websites that I have created (I haven't made any as of yet), and it will not be a blog site also. Will this kind of web hosting plan be enough for me?

- 500MB space
- 7GB traffic/mo - bandwidth
- costs something like $1.5 a month.

Another details is I'll be using Google Fonts so would it eat up more traffic?

Answer (score 2):

Using Google Fonts will not use up any additional bandwidth as you're pulling the data from Google's servers rather than your own.

The main thing to consider, if you're expecting a lot of traffic is bandwidth. If it's a small portfolio website with just a few images you may find your total site's size weighing in at 1MB. This will obviously give you a minimum of 7200~ requests, and that's based on every single resource being hit per visit which isn't going to happen.

If you're expecting this, or less, then that hosting plan would be more than suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You never really know what is enough until you see the load to your server. However, a small portfolio site takes up next to nothing in terms of space and bandwidth. Therefore, I would start with that and move to a higher cost package if necessary.

Google fonts are loaded from Google's servers. All you do is point to them so it is pretty much zero bandwidth.